# Project for the game 'Oware'

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a project about the game "Oware", we are supposed to write the game in the program Dr.Racket.
These are the rules for the game, they explain it pretty well, illustrating with pictures: http://www.awale.info/jugar-a-lawale/les-regles-de-lawale/?lang=en
Im kinda stuck on the first exercise, i have the method, but its not giving the numbers in the right order.

The first function we have to write is called "distribute" which should re-put x grains in the holes, giving the result in a form of a list consisting of the number of grains rest and the new numbers for the holes.

This is whats expected:

```
(distribute 5 '(2 3 1 5 5 2)) -> (0 (3 4 2 6 6 2))
(distribute 5 '(2 3 1))       -> (2 (3 4 2))
```

What I wrote:

```
(define distribue
  (lambda (n l)
    (if (or (= n 0) (null? l))
        (list l n)
        (cons (+ (car l) 1) (distribue (- n 1) (cdr l))))))
```

What it gives:

```
(distribue 5 '(2 3 1 5 5 2))  -> (3 4 2 6 6 (2) 0)
(distribue 5 '(2 3 1))        -> (3 4 2 () 2)
```

I was trying to change the list cons append, but never got the expected form of answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
(define (distribue n l)
  (define (iterator n p q)
    (if (or (= n 0) (null? q))
        (list n (append p q))
        (iterator (- n 1) (append p (list (+ 1 (car q)))) (cdr q))))
  (iterator n '() l))
```

where

```
(distribue 5 '(2 3 1 5 5 2))
(distribue 5 '(2 3 1))
```

returns

```
'(0 (3 4 2 6 6 2))
'(2 (3 4 2))
```

as required.

Comment: Thank you for the help, tho i have some questions. We never wrote codes in this context, we write define then lambda. What is the difference between the two, and what is the iterator in the code you wrote? and the p? (if i got it right, the n is the same as for me, and the q is the list)

Comment: (define (fxy x y) (+ x y) is more or less the same as (define fxy (lambda (x y) (+ x y)))    p is the first part of the list (where we have added a bean to each cup), q is the second part of the list (where beans may still need to be added).

Comment: Ahhh okay, i think i got it now. Somewhy i thought that the iterator is an other predefined code, just realised that its not the case. Thank you a lot:)